# Kernel32.dll Header information

Tags: c++, dll, portable-executable

Following is a dump of the first several bytes of Kernel32.dll on 64 Bit Windows 8. The offset to PE signature is f8 stored at location 3c. The values at f8 (50 45 00 00) seem to denote the appropriate PE signature which is supposed to be followed by the machine type which in this case is expected to be 014C for IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_I386 but what we find is 64 86. Any ideas on this apparent discrepancy?? I know I might be missing upon a lot of knowledge on the way dll's appear on the disk and the way they do after being loaded in memory. What I'm looking for are sources from where I can build upon.
Any information would be highly appreciated.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 0x8664 == IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 == 64-bit version of the file.  Have a look at c:\windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll instead.

Answer (score 1):

The 6486 there means IMAGE_FILE_MACHINE_AMD64 witch is correct since you are on a 64 bit machine. Kernel32.dll is not a 32 bit dll, the name kernel32 is just a name and it is the same on 32 and 64 bit machines.